# javascript client can't in docker-compose service can't fetch from node.js api

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, docker-compose, fetch-api

I have a docker-compose.yml (test setup) file that contains 3 services: a nodes api (api), a html php frontend (clientphp) and a html/javascript frontend which should replace the php frontend but I can't get it working (clientjs).

1. a Node.js api that returns a JSON object called **api**

> ```
> {
>   "products": [
>     "icecream",
>     "milk",
>     "fries",
>     "cheese",
>     "oranges",
>     "bananas"
>   ]
> }
> ```

2. a html page with php code fetching the json from http://api:3000/ and creating an ul called **clientphp**. *Works fine!*

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>My Shop</title> 
    </head> <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my shop</h1> 
    <ul>
        <?php
        $json = file_get_contents('http://api:3000/'); 
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $products = $obj->products;
        foreach ($products as $product) { 
            echo "<li>$product</li>";
        }
        ?> 
</ul>  </body> </html>
```

3. a javascript client trying to fetch the code from the api which won't work at all. It can't find http://api:3000/. If I replace the service name with the IP address of the container I just a random error about an unhandled promise rejection. This service is called **clientjs**

```
  fetch('http://api:3000/', { mode: 'no-cors'})        //this won't work, replacing the api in the url with the IP address will the server not found error. 
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.table(data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  });
```

```
[Log] TypeError: Load failed (index.js, line 30)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Not implemented on this platform
    (anonymous function)
    rejectPromise
    reject
    (anonymous function) (content-script.js:80:377615)
    n (content-script.js:80:115)
    (anonymous function) (content-script.js:80:906)
    Global Code (content-script.js:80:915)
[Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. (api, line 0)
[Log] TypeError: Load failed (index.js, line 30)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -y
COPY index.js ./ 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node index.js
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 5001:3000
  client:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./clientjs:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    ports:
      - 5002:80
    depends_on:
      - api
  php-client:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./clientphp:/var/www/html
    ports: 
      - 5003:80
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP is running on the *client* docker instance. Requests from it come from that *client* to *api* inside the virtual network created by the Docker Compose configuration.

The JavaScript is served from the *client* docker instance to the browser (which isn't running in the virtual network) and the JavaScript is executed **in the browser**.

The browser can't find `http://api:3000` because it isn't part of that virtual network.

The API ports configuration is `5001:3000` so, if I remember my Docker correctly, you need to be making the request to `http://localhost:5001/`

Comment: It does make a lot of sense when you put it like that, thx!